# Error while add data in database SQL Server 2016

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Currently, I have one table in my database called 'factory'. In this table, there are two columns, 'Fac_ID' and 'Fac_Name'. Now, I want to create a function to add some new factory to the table 'factory'.

The value of 'Fac_ID' and 'Fac_Name' must be same, which mean when I want to add factory 'F09', the value of Fac_ID and Fac_Name must be same which is 'F09'.

When I used to connect with MYSQL database (PDO), the addition is successful. BUt when i change to MSSQL (PDO),

> " Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\ebooking\add_factory.php:24 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ebooking\add_factory.php(24): PDOStatement->bindParam(':Fac_ID', 'F11')"

Here is my code for add_factory.php

```
<?php

require_once "configPDO.php";

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {   
$Fac_ID = $_POST['Fac_ID'];

// checking empty fields
if(empty($Fac_ID)) {

    if(empty($Fac_ID)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Name field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }
    //link to the previous page
    echo "<br/><a href='javascript:self.history.back();'>Go Back</a>";
} else { 
    // if all the fields are filled (not empty) 

    //insert data to database       
    $sql = "INSERT INTO factory(Fac_Name, Fac_ID) VALUES(:Fac_Name, :Fac_Name)";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $query->bindParam(':Fac_Name', $Fac_ID,);
    $query->bindParam(':Fac_ID', $Fac_ID,);
    $query->execute();


    //display success message
    header("Location:factory.php");
  }
 }

?>
```

and here is my configPDO.php

```
<?php

$servername = 'xxx.xx.xx.xxx';
$username = 'xx';
$password = 'xxxxxx';
$dbname = 'xxxx';

try {
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$servername;Database=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
catch(PDOException $error) {
$error->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Can I know what the problem? the input at HTML to add the factory is 'Fac_ID'

Comment: In your query you have `VALUES(:Fac_Name, :Fac_Name)` instead of `VALUES(:Fac_Name, :Fac_ID)`

Comment: because, like my question, I want to the Fac_ID and Fac_Name in same value

Comment: That's fine, but you are trying to bind to the parameter `:Fac_ID` and that doesn't exist in your query. Hence the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the following query

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO factory(Fac_Name, Fac_ID) VALUES(:Fac_Name, :Fac_Name)";
```

you are using :Fac_Name twice instead you should use the following

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO factory(Fac_Name, Fac_ID) VALUES(:Fac_Name, :Fac_ID)";
```

and if you need to set the same value for the name and id you should ommit the following line

```
    $query->bindParam(':Fac_ID', $Fac_ID,);
```

since you are trying to bind data to a parameter that doesnt exist in your query

the following statement is sufficent in your case

```
    $query->bindParam(':Fac_Name', $Fac_ID,);
```